# Predict number of points returned mid-point circle algorithm

Tags: algorithm, raster

The well-known mid-point circle algorithm ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm)) gives us the x,y coordinates of the pixel coordinates of a circle of given radius.

The computation it uses is iterative, and uses a condition at each iteration to exit the loop: `while (y > x) etc...`

The question I have is **how to predict in advance, given the radius, what will be the total number of point returned by the algorithm?**

My mathematical background is limited, and I could not derive it. I googled for it, and the only thing I have found is the following: http://www.gdunge.com/2011/03/23/a-different-kind-of-pi. Doug, the author of the page, mentions that he found by experimenting that `round(sqrt(2) * radius)` works for a quarter of a circle. I experimented it trying to get the whole circle, and it misses a few points.

What is the substantial law behind this number?

Comment: I'm not a mathematician either, but it seems to me that it's simply the length of the perimeter, rounded up.

Comment: @Kae: the closest formula I have found is  4 * ( round(sqrt(2)/2 * (radius-1)) + 2 ). But it fails every about 16 points...

Comment: @Kae: Also, the length of the perimeter is 2 * pi * r, and it does not have even the same slope.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I took your formula as a basis and got this:

```
floor((sqrt(2)*(radius-1)+4)/2)*8
```

And it's working just fine.

Comment: Very close -- Considering octant only, returns actual count or one greater until a radius of 16557 and then growing to 1523 more than actual at a radius of 32767 (the graphics max).

Answer (score 2):

The number of *distinct* * pixels drawn by the midpoint circle algorithm when drawing a circle of radius *r*  is
    4 round(sqrt(2) *r* )
or, equivalently,
    4 floor(sqrt(2) *r* + 1/2).

`*`Many implementations of the midpoint circle algorithm draw a number of pixels multiple times.
    The  actual number of duplicates depend on the radius and on the details of the particular
    implementation.
In particular, the number of pixels drawn, *including duplicates*, by the C#
    implementation of the algorithm in cited in the original post is
        8 floor((sqrt(2)/2) *r* + 3/4) + 4.

Comment: My formula for the number of pixels works even in those cases where the accepted answer doesn't.

Comment: Well, there you go! Explain that in the answer and it'll be fine!

Comment: Also my answer also points out the distinction between the number of _distinct_ drawn pixels and _total_ number of drawn pixels, including duplicates.  It was not clear from the poster's question which one of these he was looking for, or even if he was aware that they are different numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the diagram on the Wikipedia page you refer to, you can see that, in the first octant, every pixel is one unit above the previous pixel, and one pixel below the previous pixel, and a quick glance at the algorithm suggests that this is always the case for the octant in this position.

So the number of pixels required to draw the first octant of the circle is the number of pixels you move up in the first octant. If the radius is r, then the distance you move up in the first octant is r sin 45 degrees, which is r / sqrt(2) - at 45 degrees we have a right angled triangle with two sides of length one, and a hypotenuse of length sqrt(2).

If an octant takes r / sqrt(2), then a quarter of a circle - two octants - takes r * sqrt(2)

Comment: Thanks! I have found 4 * ( round(sqrt(2)/2 * (radius-1)) + 2 to work, but rounding problems make it fail every once in a while... I'll dig on this.